# how to find the total no.of inbound and outbound links of a website using php?

Tags: php

how to find the total no.of inbound and outbound links of a website using php?

Comment: Project-wide, server-wide, world-wide? What should it be, sir?

Comment: You could use `preg_match_all` using `'<a\s.*href=".+".*>'` to get all the anchor elements. Then you could compare the anchors URL's domains to the URL of the website.

Comment: I hope this is useful for you. Its for finding total number of inbound and outbound links checker. Find [here](http://www.phphunger.com/2012/06/inbound-and-outbound-links-checker.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count outbound links

- parse html for webpage
- parse all links using regex
- filter links which starts with your domain or "/"

To inbound link

- Grab google results page
- http://www.google.ca/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=site:
- parse similarly

Answer (score 1):

For outbound links, you will have to parse the HTML code of the website as some here have suggested.

For inbound links, I suggest using the Google Custom Search API, sending a direct request to google can get your ip banned. You can view the search api [here](http://code.google.com/apis/customsearch/v1/overview.html). Here is a function I use in my code for this api:

```
  function doGoogleSearch($searchTerm)
  {
    $referer = 'http://your-site.com';
    $args['q'] = $searchTerm;        
    $endpoint = 'web';
    $url = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/".$endpoint;

    $args['v'] = '1.0';
    $key= 'your-api-key';


    $url .= '?'.http_build_query($args, '', '&');

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);        
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $referer);
    $body = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    //decode and return the response
    return json_decode($body);
  }
```

After calling this function as: `$result = doGoogleSearch('link:site.com')`, the variable `$result->cursor->estimatedResultCount` will have the number of results returned.

Comment: thanks dude.You gave me the exact answer.im going to workout this code after that i will get back to you.Thanks alot.

Comment: if im running this code within my localhost server what i want to put in the referer variable?

Comment: dude it worked well.actually i got a json content from curl_exec() before you encoded it.now i want to get all the values of  url in the Json format of that data.

Comment: @sirin I'm not sure what you mean? If you read the documentation that I linked to, you will probably find what you're looking for

Comment: i want to find the url from results page returned from the google's api

Comment: @sirin You mean the urls of the links found? I suggest you do a print_r on $result to see how you might access it. I'm not sure if its possible to get the URLs through this method or not, for that you might need to use yahoo site explorer. Your question was about how to get the no. of links, that's what my function provides ;)

Comment: hello but the json format contains all the urls.i just want to get all of them using php.

Comment: @sirin If you do json_decode() on the variable that has the JSON string like shown in the code here, you should have a PHP object which has got everything

Comment: im getting an error like this:Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Comment: @ Click Upvote:i got the results from google api.but it contains only 1'st 4 links in the results page.how to get those 10 links?

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't determine the inbound links of a page through some trivial action.  You either have to monitor all incoming visitors and check what their referrer is, or parse the entire internet for links that point to that site.  The first method will miss links not getting used, and the second method is best left to Google.

On the other hand, the outbound links from a site is doable.  You can read in a page and analyze the text for links with a regular expression, counting up the total.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getGoogleLinks($host)
{

    $request = "http://www.google.com/search?q=" . urlencode("link:" . $host) ."&hl=en";

    $data = getPageData($request);
    preg_match('/<div id=resultStats>(About )?([\d,]+) result/si', $data, $l);
    $value = ($l[2]) ? $l[2] : "n/a";
    $string = "<a href=\"" . $request . "\">" . $value . "</a>";
    return $string;
}
//$host means the domain name
```

Comment: if not works '& amp' should be changed to '&amp' (ie no space b/w &and amp)